# TextView text changes but does not update in layout (Kotlin - Android)

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, refresh, invalidation

TextView text changes but does not update in layout. I tried every method I could find but nothing worked. I have a very basic application with a single activity and 3 layouts*.
<sup>*This is the first app I make so I tought it would have been simpler this way</sup>
The main problems I am facing are two: almost all the informations around are old and in java, and my textView text does not change.. The app is a simple Rock-Paper-Scissor game I'm trying to make as an exercise.

The textViews.text values get updated but the layout always shows the same text...
I have no idea what could be the problem. I am also struggling to understand exactly how all of this is working exactly...like InflateLayout, Context and Android in general. I do not understand much from android's reference.

*THERE IS NO INFLATE(), POSTINFLATE(), FORCELAYOUT(), VISIBILITY TOGGLES BECAUSE NONE OF THEM WORKED :(*

**Excerpt of the code**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var TITLE:TextView
lateinit var PARAGRAPH:TextView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState :Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val InflaterInitializer = LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext) as LayoutInflater
    val inflater = InflaterInitializer.inflate(R.layout.activity_2, null, false)

    TITLE= inflater.findViewById(R.id.title) as TextView
    PARAGRAPH= inflater.findViewById(R.id.paragraph) as TextView

}
```

**There are three functions like this:**

```
fun FUNCTION(v :View) {
    val userChoice = "XXX"
    val computerChoice = getComputerChoice()
    if (userChoice == computerChoice) {
        FUNCTION_2(computerChoice)
    } else {
        runOnUiThread {
            TITLE.text =
                if (computerChoice == "YYY") getString(R.string.YOU_WON) else getString(R.string.YOU_LOSE);
            PARAGRAPH.text = getString(R.string.STRING, computerChoice)
        }
    }; resultScreen()
}
```

**Function_2...**

```
private fun FUNCTION_2(cc :String) {
    runOnUiThread {
        TITLE.text = getString(R.string.STRING)
        PARAGRAPH.text = getString(R.string.STRING, cc)
    }; resultScreen()
}
```

resultScreen() is just a call to setContentView(LAYOUT)

Here's a video of the app and the update problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNuTe.jpg

Code complete here: https://github.com/noiwyr/MorraCinese

---

**EDIT**
Unfortunately none of the answers actually worked as I hoped, however redesigning the app and using multiple activities with some tweaks solved the issue. You may find the new code in the github repo.

However I would be curious to know if there is a working solution for this question :)

Comment: in kotlin don't you have to call setText() method, if you don't understand android where did you copy the code from, i suggest taking a good course or grab a good book

Comment: @abhinav-chauhan I'm not sure I understood correctly your comment, however I used .text= instead of setText() because this is what android studio suggested me. At the moment I have a book on kotlin ("Head First Kotlin") but I read only the first pages because I was eager to start doing something. Do you have some better recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

By calling `InflaterInitializer.inflate(R.layout.activity_2, null, false)` you inflate a new view hierarchy from the specified xml resource, which is not attached to any of your views (these new views are not shown on your screen). Then you found text views from that **new** view hierarchy and changed their titles.

So, your `onCreate` method have to look like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState :Bundle?) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_2)

   TITLE = findViewById(R.id.title)
   PARAGRAPH = findViewById(R.id.paragraph)
}
```

Also, it's redundant to use methods `runOnUiThread()` (your code already runs on Ui thread) and `resultScreen()`.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. 
I shall leave this lateinit var TITLE:TextView right? Otherwise, how do I access these variables?

Comment: Yes, you must keep that lines. But in kotlin you can access your views via their names in xml, eg. `title.text = getString(R.string.STRING)`

Answer (score 0):

You no need anything  , you creat over code no problem I suggest you

val InflaterInitializer = LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext) as LayoutInflater val inflater = InflaterInitializer.inflate(R.layout.activity_outcome, null, false)

Comment this above code no need in kotlin

motivoRisultato.text = getString(R.string.scelta_pc, computerChoice)

Simpaly make this type of code

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few errors in your code, so I'm going to break down the answer with your code. Do find the Comments inline

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    /**
    * First, Follow conventions for naming variables, they are usually in camelcase for variables and functions, Capitalized for Constants.
    * Second, lateinit is used to defer the initialization of a variable, for views, such as 
    * TextView's, you could use the Kotlin Synthentic library which automatically references the Views of your layout. 
    */
    lateinit var TITLE:TextView
    lateinit var PARAGRAPH:TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState :Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        /** 
        * Set content view, internally set's the layout file after inflation using the Activity context. Which means, that you do not 
        * need to specifically inflate the view. 
        */
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        /**
        * This is the reason why your layout doesn't know refresh, what you're doing here is inflating another layout, but not setting it to your activity. 
        * This is not required as explained above
        */
        val InflaterInitializer = LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext) as LayoutInflater
        /**
        * Inflater inflates a View Object. one would use this approach if they were programatically adding Views 
        */
        val inflater = InflaterInitializer.inflate(R.layout.activity_2, null, false)

        /**
        * the below views are pointing to a reference of TextView for the non visible inflated view. Which is the reason why the text is not updated. 
        */
        TITLE= inflater.findViewById(R.id.title) as TextView
        PARAGRAPH= inflater.findViewById(R.id.paragraph) as TextView

    }
}
```

Here's the code to make things work

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var title:TextView? = null
    private var paragraph:TextView? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState :Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        title= inflater.findViewById(R.id.title) as TextView
        paragraph= inflater.findViewById(R.id.paragraph) as TextView

    }

    fun function(v :View) {
        val userChoice = "XXX"
        val computerChoice = getComputerChoice()
        if (userChoice == computerChoice) {
            function2(computerChoice)
        } else {
            title.text = if (computerChoice == "YYY") getString(R.string.YOU_WON) else getString(R.string.YOU_LOSE);
            paragraph.text = getString(R.string.STRING, computerChoice)

        } 
        resultScreen()
    }

    private fun function2(cc :String) { 
       title.text = getString(R.string.STRING)
       paragraph.text = getString(R.string.STRING, cc)
       resultScreen()
    }
}
```

If your use case is to show different screens, look at starting more than one Activity and transitioning between them using [Intents](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters)

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I tried your method but it was problematic.. I had to set all title and paragraph occurance in "safe mode", with ? which raised a nullException with the text.

PS: in the original code I named variables and function in a better way, I tought that with this kind of names the code would have been more relatable for other people with the same doubts I have :)

Comment: the reason for the optional (?) is because, there are chances that one might attach the wrong layout or even delete an Id, and subsequently try finding it. By Safe Unwrapping it, there is a guarantee that the value is not null.

Comment: Regarding Naming conventions: The point is to make sure other's who read your code understand what you're doing. In your code, if choose to use caps for every variable, how would you identify if a variable is static/final?